# nginx does not detect ssi comments and do the correct substitution

Tags: nginx, ssi

I'm using nginx 1.14.2 on a Debian 10 system. I can't get SSI to work using all the recommendations posted on this site that I could find. Here's where I set SSI on in the server section of my virtual host. Placing this inside the nginx.conf file doesn't help:

```
location / {
    ssi on;
}
```

Here's what's inside the test HTML file, called ssi.shtml:

```
<body>
    <!--#include file="ssitest.shtml" -->
</body>
```

It also doesn't work with this line:

```
<!--#include virtual="ssitest.shtml" -->
```

Here's the ssitest.shtml file contents:

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

The two files are in the same directory. It doesn't matter if these two files have a .shtml or .html extension. When I look at the source in the browser, I see the comment, not "Hello".

The output from nginx -V does not include ngx_http_ssi_module or any similar name with "ssi" or "include" in it. I downloaded nginx source and compiled it. It too does not show ngx_http_ssi_module in nginx -V output.

What's up? Help, please.

Comment: `ngx_http_ssi_module` is a built-in nginx module and it is normal to not being listed within the `nginx -V` output. The fact you don't receive an error at the `ssi on;` configuration line is another confirmation of its presence. Everything is ok with your config, just give it a test and both SSI test files (`include file` and `include virtual`) are giving an expected output. Of course it isn't an answer to your question...